# Modifying svg:path using d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I've been working on this problem for a while, and i'm stumped :(

I have one svg which contains some buttons i've made. Then in another svg I have a chart with various lines or svg:path's. When I click a button, I want a specific line to change color. I have the following code:

```
buttons.selectAll("#infoBox")
   .data(mydata)
   .enter()
   .append("svg:image")

... some attributes here ...

   .on("click", function() 
    {
       linechart.selectAll("svg.path")    

//right now i'm just selecting all the paths                                          
//because i want to check to see if it works 

                .style("stroke", "red");

    }
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? You can view my code [here](http://www.sonia-kandah.com) if you need more info about how i'm structuring everything (i'm a beginner at javascript, html and css so sorry if my code isn't very clear or concise)

Thanks for any and all help :)

Answer (score 0):

`selectAll("svg.path")` selects all `svg` elements that have a class `path`. Not sure if that is what you really want. If you want to select all `path` elements within the `svg` elements, you should say: `selectAll("svg path")`.

I couldn't find the variable `linechart` in the link you provided. If `linechart` refers to the selection of `svg` elements, than simply saying `linechart.selectAll("path")` would be sufficient.